# MongoDB append `$or` operator if condition is met

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have this mongoDB query:

```
var condition = {}

if(filter == 'date'){
 condition.date = {$gte: 'xx',$lt: 'xx'}
}else{
 condition = {
  $or: [
    name: {
     $regex: 'xxx'
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

how can i combine it like this:

```
    condition = {
     date: {
      $gte: 'xx',
      $lt: 'xx'
     },
     $or: [
      name: {
       $regex: 'xxx'
      }
     ]
    }
```

i should append the `$or` operator if and only if the `name textbox` is not empty

Comment: You can add an additional condition (using `$and`) to your query that `name` field is `$ne` _empty_ (`""`).

Comment: This is more of a javascript question. Just like you do `condition.date =`, you can do `condition.$or =`